# Scaling of Azure SQL reserve instance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have Azure SQL reserve instance for 3 years. Can I increase the capacity i.e. scale out or not when it is reserved for 3 years?

Answer (score 0):

You can **Exchange Reservations** to increase the capacity of Azure SQL reserve instance.

You have to purchase new reservation that must be of equal or greater value than original reservation.

You can exchange reservations for another reservation of the same type. For example, you can exchange multiple SQL database reservation types including Managed Instances and Elastic Pool with each other.

You can return multiple existing reservations to purchase one new reservation of the same type. You can't exchange reservations of one type for another. For example, you can't return a VM reservation to purchase a SQL reservation. **You can change a reservation property such as family, series, version, SKU, region, quantity, and term with an exchange.**

There's no penalty or annual limits for exchanges.

For more information follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/exchange-and-refund-azure-reservations)